# backbone Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: backbone.js, view, push

i'm working with Backbone and when I generate the view I have the error Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". The line of the error is "self.subViewsReservas.push(new ReservaView({" in the push.

```
    ReservaCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function () {
    if (Session.get('authenticated') && Session.get('authenticated') !== false) {
        this.paginacionVista = new PaginacionReservasView({
            collection: this.collection,
            el: '.paginacionReservas',
            reservasPagina: 5,
        });
        this.buscadorVista = new BuscadorView({
            el: 'div.buscador-reservas',
            //Pasamos la colección oficinas ya que hará las veces del conjunto de oficinas retornadas por el servidor
            collection: new OficinasCollection(oficinas),
        });
    }
    else {
    }
},
render: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.template = _.template($('#divReservaTpl').html(), {});
    self.$('.contenedor-reservas').empty();
    self.collection.each(function (reserva, index) {
        self.$('.contenedor-reservas').append(self.template({'data': reserva.toJSON()}));
    });
    this.collection.each(function (reserva, index) {
      this.subViewsReservas = [];
          self.subViewsReservas.push(new ReservaView({
              el: '#' + reserva.get('Idreserva'),
              model: reserva
          }));
    });
    this.collection.each(function (reserva, index) {
        //Limite de la paginacion 5 limite arbitrario
        if (index < 5) {
            //Lo Marcamos como visible y actualiazamos la paginación
            self.collection.get(reserva.get('Idreserva')).set({'Visibilidad': true});
        }
    });

    this.paginacionVista.render();

    return this;
},
```

});

```
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
            var self = this;

            self.usu = new UsuarioModel();
            self.usu.fetch({
                success: function (model){
                    Session.fetch({
                        success : function (){

                            Session.set('nombre',model.get('Nombre'));
                            Session.set('apellidos',model.get('Apellidos'));
                            Session.set('puntos_club',model.get('Puntosclub'));

                            self.render();
                        }
                    });

                    self.sideBar = new SideBarView({
                        el : '.sidebar',
                        model: model
                    });
                    self.sideBar.markOption('mis-reservas');
            AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
            var self = this;

            self.usu = new UsuarioModel();
            self.usu.fetch({
                success: function (model){
                    Session.fetch({
                        success : function (){

                            Session.set('nombre',model.get('Nombre'));
                            Session.set('apellidos',model.get('Apellidos'));
                            Session.set('puntos_club',model.get('Puntosclub'));

                            self.render();
                        }
                    });

                    self.sideBar = new SideBarView({
                        el : '.sidebar',
                        model: model
                    });
                    self.sideBar.markOption('mis-reservas');
                },
                error : function (){
                    document.location = '/mygoldcar/login';
                }
            });            

            this.listenTo(Session, 'change', self.update);        
    },
    render : function(){
            var self = this;
            var reservas = new ReservasCollection();
            reservas.fetch({
                success: function (collection){
                    if ( typeof collection.models[0].get('error') == 'undefined' || !collection.models[0].get('error')) {
                        var listRes = new ReservaCollectionView({
                            el : '.reservas-list',
                            collection: collection   
                        });
                        listRes.render();

                        var popoverModel = new Popover();
                        popoverModel.setData(collection.models[0].get('kilometraje_ilimitado'), collection.models[0].get('duracion'));

                        self.popover = new PopoverView({
                            el: 'body',
                            model: popoverModel
                        });

                        self.popover.establecerPopover();
                    }
                    else document.location = '/mygoldcar' + self.urlLang(lang) + '/mi-cuenta/#msg/1';                    
                },
                error: function () {
                    document.location = '/mygoldcar' + self.urlLang(lang) + '/mi-cuenta/#msg/1';                    
                }
            });
    },
        update: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.sideBar.update(Session.get('nombre'),Session.get('apellidos'),Session.get('puntos_club'));   
            self.$el.find('.nombre-usuario').text(Session.get('nombre'));            
        },
        updatePoints: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.usu.fetch({
                success: function (model){
                    Session.set('puntos_club',model.get('Puntosclub'));
                }
            });
        }   
});    },
                error : function (){
                    document.location = '/mygoldcar/login';
                }
            });            

            this.listenTo(Session, 'change', self.update);        
    },
    render : function(){
            var self = this;
            var reservas = new ReservasCollection();
            reservas.fetch({
                success: function (collection){
                    if ( typeof collection.models[0].get('error') == 'undefined' || !collection.models[0].get('error')) {
                        var listRes = new ReservaCollectionView({
                            el : '.reservas-list',
                            collection: collection   
                        });
                        listRes.render();

                        var popoverModel = new Popover();
                        popoverModel.setData(collection.models[0].get('kilometraje_ilimitado'), collection.models[0].get('duracion'));

                        self.popover = new PopoverView({
                            el: 'body',
                            model: popoverModel
                        });

                        self.popover.establecerPopover();
                    }
                    else document.location = '/mygoldcar' + self.urlLang(lang) + '/mi-cuenta/#msg/1';                    
                },
                error: function () {
                    document.location = '/mygoldcar' + self.urlLang(lang) + '/mi-cuenta/#msg/1';                    
                }
            });
    },
        update: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.sideBar.update(Session.get('nombre'),Session.get('apellidos'),Session.get('puntos_club'));   
            self.$el.find('.nombre-usuario').text(Session.get('nombre'));            
        },
        updatePoints: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.usu.fetch({
                success: function (model){
                    Session.set('puntos_club',model.get('Puntosclub'));
                }
            });
        }   
});
```

Comment: Move `this.subViewsReservas = [];` outside of your `each()` (move it 2 lines up). While it doesnt explain your `push is not defined` error, that just seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `collection.each`, `this` points to the collection. So the property `subViewsReservas` is added to it, not the view instance. When you try to access it like `self.subViewsReservas.push`, `self` points to the view instance, which doesn't have `subViewsReservas` property, hence the error.

Initializing an array inside `each` like you're doing isn't doing much since it'll be reset with each invocation of the callback.

You should be initializing it in the `initialize` method, which is the right place to *initialize* things, where `this` will correctly point to the view instance as shown below

```
initialize: function () {
  this.subViewsReservas = [];
}
```

---

For some reason if you want the collection to reset everytime, you can change the context to view by passing it as second argument to each like:

```
this.collection.each(function (reserva, index) {
  this.subViewsReservas = [];
      self.subViewsReservas.push(new ReservaView({
          el: '#' + reserva.get('Idreserva'),
          model: reserva
      }));
}, self); // <--- makes view the context of callback,
          // both 'self' and 'this' will refer to view
```